# How to apply sunburstR on 3 level hierarchies?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, sunburst-diagram

How can we represent all the different hierarchies in the table ? i.e.

- per_c_i,
- per_c,
- per_s_i

Some kind of bar chart/ stacked bar did not help

Also, sunburstR  might be too complimented to implement !

Can you suggest us how to represent all these hierarchies in a single plot/chart ?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(item = c("apple","orange","apple","banana","apple","apple"),
+                 cust = c(rep("john",2),"papa","john",rep("jerry",2)),
+                 shop = c("shop1","shop2",rep("shop1",2),rep("shop2",2)),
+                 sales = c(12,13,6,8,10,9)
+                 )

df_m <- df %>% 
+   group_by(cust,item) %>%
+   mutate(per_c_i = 100*sales/sum(sales)) %>%
+   group_by(item) %>%
+   mutate(per_c = 100* per_c_i / sum(per_c_i))

df_c <- merge(df,df_m, by = c("cust","item","shop","sales")) %>%
+   group_by(shop,item) %>%
+   mutate(per_s_i = 100*per_c/sum(per_c)) 

df_c
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   shop, item [4]
  cust  item   shop  sales per_c_i per_c per_s_i
  <fct> <fct>  <fct> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 jerry apple  shop2    10    52.6  17.5    52.6
2 jerry apple  shop2     9    47.4  15.8    47.4
3 john  apple  shop1    12   100    33.3    50  
4 john  banana shop1     8   100   100     100  
5 john  orange shop2    13   100   100     100  
6 papa  apple  shop1     6   100    33.3    50  

# Attempt via ggplot
df_c %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cust, 
             y = per_s_i, 
             fill = item)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity"#, position=position_dodge()
  ) +
  geom_col() + 
  coord_flip()

df_c %>% knitr::kable()
```

#### Applying SunburstR but doesnt render an image

```
library(d3r)
library(sunburstR)
df_s <- df_c %>% 
  rename("level1" = "cust",
         "level2" = "item",
         "level3" = "shop")

tree <- d3_nest(df_s[,c(1:2,4)], value_cols = "sales")
tree

# sunburst types
sunburst(tree, width="100%", height=400)
sunburst(
  tree,
  legend = FALSE,
  width = "100%",
  height = 400
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Data visualization is inherently subjective, there are many ways you could visualize the data and the 'best' way will heavily depend on data context and researcher preference.

Since you are basically working with a three way design ('cust', 'item' and 'per') it can be difficult to capture all of this information effectively in a single plot. One option would be to use faceting so you can present each variable in a different panel. In order to do this you would need to transform the data from wide format to long format so your variables of interest ('per' variables) are in a single column, with the wide column names as a new factor.

```
# Reshape the data from wide to long
library(reshape2)
df_l <- melt(df_c[colnames(df_c) %in% c("cust", "item", "per_c_i", "per_c", "per_s_i")], 
             id.vars = c("cust", "item"))

#plot the data, faceting by 'hierarchy'
ggplot(df_l, aes(x = cust, y = value, fill = item)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(variable))
```

[image]